# How to create unique index in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Service that handles with accounts has route for adding new account. Obviously, email field in account should be unique. 
I want app to throw error any time when matches founded.

At this moment it is realized via manually function:

```
const { createError } = require('micro')

const createAccount = async (collection, credentials) => {
  const { email } = credentials
  const account = await collection.findOne({ email })
  if (account) {
    throw createError(401, 'this email is already used')
  }
  collection.insertOne({ email })
}

module.exports = createAccount
```

When I used mongoose there were no problems with adding unique index. This time, native mongoDB driver was used.
According documentation I tried to add something like:

```
collection.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

And in fact, it really created an index, I can see it in my mlab home:
https://gyazo.com/8f0e36a3134154acde0b77cf2ade61a6

Maybe I used out-dated syntax or something like this? Why key has unique set to false?

Comment: Try removing that existing index from mongo and then re-running your code.

Comment: @VtoCorleone is right. That index might have already existed. You might need to drop and then recreate it.

Comment: Yeap, I tried that. In any case index has unique set to false.
Looks like there is some problem with options:
    await collection.createIndex({ email: 1 }, { unique: true })
Because index created, but there is no unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have use [ensureIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/)

```
collection.ensureIndex(option, response){
 // here call you fucntion
}
```

ensureIndex method will create index if not already there.

Comment: ensureIndex is deprecated: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/